# Counting Records COUNT or SUM or ROW?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

This table contains server monitoring records. Once the server fails to ping, it inserts new records. So one server can fail multiple times. I want to get the count of records how many times SERVER 3 fails.

This is the table where `failure_id` is Primary Key.

```
failure_id  server_id  protocol  added_date           
----------  ---------  --------  ---------------------
         1          1  HTTP      2013-02-04 15:50:42  
         2          3  HTTP      2013-02-04 16:35:20
```

Using (*) to count the rows

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS `total` 
FROM
  `failures` `f` 
WHERE CAST(`f`.`server_id` AS CHAR) = 3;
```

Using server_id to count the rows

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(`f`.`server_id`) AS `total` 
FROM
  `failures` `f` 
WHERE CAST(`f`.`server_id` AS CHAR) = 3;
```

Using SUM to count the rows

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(1), 0) AS `total` 
FROM
  `failures` `f` 
WHERE CAST(`f`.`server_id` AS CHAR) = 3;
```

All the above queries return the correct output. But my database will be very large in the future. Which method is best to use based on performance? Thanks in advance...

Comment: The `Count(*)` is the optimal. You should be able to answer this question yourself. Increase the size of your database and get some perf metrics? Add some index's, etc etc. Then report back with the results in your question...

Comment: If performance is a concern, why are you casting server_id to a char?

Comment: if not cast `WHERE f.server_id = '3xyz23'` will be taken as just 3.

Comment: Your server_id field is not an int?  That seems odd.  Use COUNT(*) -- that can utilize more table indexes.  Make sure you have an index on your server_id field.  Other than than, test it out!  Good luck.

Comment: Even it is `INT` run this query in your tables `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM failures f WHERE f.server_id = '3xyz23'` it will just take 3.

Comment: One more query : select count(*) from failures group by server_id having server_id=3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say none of the above. If you have control over the app that's inserting the records that is. If so, if you don't have a table for your servers, just create one. otherwise add a field called `current_failure_count` or something and stick it in that table. So when you insert the record, also do an update on your server table and set `current_failure_count = current_failure_count + 1` for that server. That way you have to only read one record in the server table (indexed by `server_id` I'd assume) and you're set. No, this does not follow any of the normalization rules, but you are seeking speed and this is the best way to get it if you can control the client software.

If you cannot control the client software, perhaps you can put a trigger on the insert of records into the failures table that increments the `current_failure_count` value in the servers table. that should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second is definitely more efficient than the first.
I recommend you create a view for the server, which will severely speed things up

```
CREATE VIEW server3 AS
SELECT server_id
FROM failures
CAST(`f`.`server_id` AS CHAR) = 3;
```

Then Simply run a count on that view as if it was a table!

Comment: What makes you think that creating a view will speed the query?  That is not, in fact, true.

Comment: Also, the second query is not more efficient than the first.

Comment: Hmm, I'm new to SQL but had been told specifying columns is more efficient than just using *
And Your right, I got mixed up with indexes. Probably best I hold off answering questions on it until im a bit more knowledgeable!

Comment: That is true when you are actually returning a result set -- the "narrower" the result set the faster it will be.  But when used in aggregation operations, `*` simply means "a row".  So `COUNT(*)` means "count the rows where the condition is true".  It is no less efficient than `COUNT(column_name)` and sometimes *more* efficient since the second version needs to inspect the actual values in `column_name` for NULLs (NULLs aren't counted).  Perhaps more importantly the two versions can return different results.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, it's not clear to me why you're casting the server_id value.  That is going to cost you more performance than any other issue.

If you can eliminate that cast so that you're searching `WHERE server_id = (value)` and you create an index on `server_id` then either of the first two queries you suggested will be able to perform index-only retrieval and will provide optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total`
FROM  failures f
WHERE f.server_id = 3;
```

`count(*)` will always be better than the arithmetic calculation, although applying index will give more faster result in this.

second best solution will be

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(1), 0) AS `total`
FROM failures `f`
WHERE f.server_id  = 3;
```

this method is used my SQL engine of many tools such as microstrategy

hope answer helps...:)